# ajax success function with callback

Tags: jquery

I need to add a callback to the `$.ajax()` success callback function. I am working in jQuery 1.3

```
success : ajaxCartFormSubmitted(),

function ajaxCartFormSubmitted(e) {
  longRunningOperation();
  if (e)...
});
```

My function which should run after `ajaxCartFormSubmitted()` is:

```
function modalopen () {
  if ($('#ajax-cart-popup .full').length) {
    openmodal('ajax-cart-popup');
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

I tried to add callback to `ajaxCartFormSubmitted(e)` like this `ajaxCartFormSubmitted(e, callback)` and use it like this `success : ajaxCartFormSubmitted('modalopen()'),`
but I get no results, it seems that the function is not firing. Is the problem in first `e` argument? Thank you.

Update: I need to fire modalopen function after the ajaxCartFormSubmitted function. Ideally in the success callback.

Comment: Note that you need to pass the function *reference*, ie, `success: ajaxCartFormSubmitted,`. Secondly note that jQuery 1.3 is over 10 years out of date. You need to update it

Comment: the arguments of success function are predefined, check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You could also `return $.ajax(...` and use `.done()`

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues here. Firstly you need to pass a function *reference* to `success`. By invoking the function immediately you're actually assigning its return value to `success`, hence nothing appears to happen. To fix that simply remove the parentheses from the function name:

```
success: ajaxCartFormSubmitted,
```

Next, to have `modalopen()` execute after `ajaxCartFormSubmitted()` you need to call it at that time. Passing the name of the function as an argument alone is not enough. You need to expressly call the function. You can either do this in `ajaxCartFormSubmitted()`:

```
function ajaxCartFormSubmitted(e) {
  // do something...

  modalopen();
});
```

Alternatively you can provide an anonymous function to `success` which calls both functions:

```
success: function() {
  ajaxCartFormSubmitted();
  modalopen();
},
```

Finally, a couple of notes. You *need* to update jQuery as 1.3 is over 10 years out of date. 3.4 is the latest version. Also I'd be careful with your function names. You appear to have both `openmodal()` and `modalopen()`, and that kind of similarity is just asking for problems.

*Edit*

> The ajaxCartFormSubmitted function contains another function which needs some time to process. That is why I need to call my function after ajaxCartFormSubmitted

In which case you need to implement the callback pattern, as `$.ajax()` does, yourself. You can make `ajaxCartFormSubmitted()` accept a function as an argument which will be executed after the async operation completes, like this:

```
// in $.ajax settings:
success: function() {
  ajaxCartFormSubmitted(openmodal);
}

// function definition:
function ajaxCartFormSubmitted(cb) {
  some.longRunningOperation({
    oncomplete: function() {
      cb && cb(); // invoke the function you passed in here, openmodal() in this case
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The ajaxCartFormSubmitted function contains another function which needs some time to process. That is why I need to call my function after ajaxCartFormSubmitted

Comment: In which case you need to implement the callback pattern yourself. I've updated the answer to give you a rough idea

Comment: than you, one more question why should not I use callback ajaxCartFormSubmitted(e, callback) like this?

Comment: Ok, so (cb) means callback? The function is written originally like this ajaxCartFormSubmitted(e) should I just remove the (e)?

Comment: That would depend entirely on what value you're expecting `e` to have. With regard to the code I wrote, I just named the argument `cb`, short for 'callback'. It can be named anything at all which is a valid JS identifier

Comment: I am confused a bit - you suggesting that I should call openmodal inside some.runnongoperation function. But I do not want that. The longrunningoperation is called on various places elsewhere and I just want to run my code after ajaxCartFormSubmitted (which contains longrunningoperation function)

Comment: I'm making assumptions about the long running function as your question doesn't given details about it. It would be worth you starting a new question about that as it wasn't mentioned in your original question at all.

Comment: I updated my question, sorry for not being detailed enough.